# How to add a Count function to a UILabel

Tags: ios, swift

I am making an app where you can add contacts to it. What I want to do is add up all the contacts in this array that i created and add it to a UILabel on the homepage.
In the contacts.swift file I created a function

```
func countContacts() {
   print(contactsArray.count)
}
```

the contactsArray is my array that I have all the contacts in, even the new ones added. Now on the homepage I want to display the number of contacts I have. I wrote this code

```
myLabel2.text = String(contacts.countContacts())
```

myLabel2 is the label that I want to put the amount of contacts that I have into. I just feel like I'm not doing it right. How would you add a function to a UILabel? Any help would be very much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

`print` will just print/log the count in your debug console. You need to assign the string to your label's text:

```
myLabel2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @(contactsArray.count)];
```

Comment: So instead of print do i use a return?

Comment: You could but you don't need to to that, unless you want to have a function doing some special counting logic. Just cast Integer to string, and assign it to the `text`

Answer (score 0):

```
myLabel2.text = String(contactsArray.count)
```

will work

Answer (score 0):

```
func countContacts() -> String {
  return String(contactsArray.count)
}

myLabel2.text = contacts.countContacts()
```